# Why is the word "impeding" used as synonym for "imminent"?

Tags: word-usage

As far as I can tell, every dictionary definition ([example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/impeding)) of "impede" talks about blocking, delaying, retard in movement... "impeding" something from happening. The word seems to [come from a Latin expression](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impede#Etymology) meaning "to shackle the feet".

And yet, I see in daily use it is very common to use "impeding" to refer to something imminent, something that will happen sooner or later, and most likely impossible to stop. Example: "[the impeding demise of ...](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20impeding%20demise%20of%22)".

What's the explanation for this usage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question was based on a typo.

Comment: It's a toyp. The word is **impending**, with an N. It means 'hanging over', so _your impending demise_ means _you will die soon_.

Comment: @JohnLawler a "toyp"?

Comment: This question is not unlikely. Intersylabic dentals come and go. Also, *again,* and *against* are an unlikely yet well known cognate, analogous to Ger *wieder, wider*. More over, G *gegen* (against) can mean "towards", also of time; the *a-* in *against* supposedly correlates with *an-* or *on* (cp *onto*); then G *angehen* means "begin", but *gegen jemanden angehen* "to resist, attack sb."; En *gain* is but the inverse of *impedance* in Electronics. What's going *on* here? *suspend* can be easily confused with *pendulum*, thus *spend*--from a mysterious root concerning *libation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually from “*to impend*” meaning to be about to happen:

***[impend (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/impend#etymonline_v_1557)***:

> - "be about to happen" (usually of something unwanted), 1590s, from Latin impendere "to hang over;" figuratively ***"to be imminent, be near,***" from assimilated form of in- "into, in, on, upon".

(Etymonline)

Evidence from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=imminent%2Cimpending&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimminent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpending%3B%2Cc0) suggests that both “imminent” and “impending” are  very  common terms.